# How can I use dragon bones?

Tags: dnd-5e, dragons

My party recently acquired some dragon bones. We split up the skeleton. I got the head and neck. One got the ribs and front legs. One got the wings and feet and one got the back legs and tail. I bought the rib cage for 125 gp. I don't know if that was a good idea but I did it. I want to know how I can use the neck bones, skull, and ribs.

Can anyone tell me what to do in this situation? Someone once suggested I use the ribs to reinforce my shield, but I don't know if that's allowed by the rules.

What are the guidelines around what can be done with dragon bones? I know I can just use them for cool decorations, but is there any rules support from getting any kind of benefit out of them?

Comment: Edited and opened along the lines suggested by Praxiteles.  @Wibbs, a question whose answer is "it depends on  your DM" is not opinion-based.  It's opinion-based if it's asking for your opinions.

Comment: Good distinction. Often "It requires a gamemaster's judgement" *is* the answer to the question.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The use of dragon bones is not mentioned anywhere in any official D&D 5e material. Ask your DM. Or, better yet, decide what your character would like to do with them, and ask your DM if it's possible.

Answer (score -3):

If I were to make a list of things to do with the bones of a dragon, I would be here for a while.

I don't think there are any rules for what you can or can't do with dragon bones. One thing you could do is use it as an improvised weapon, and use the stats for spear or javelin (pointy bone) or great club (not pointy bone). Other than that, I would just use them for whatever you want as long as your DM allows it.